# Apache doesnt run PHP after installing new PHP from source on centOS7

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos7

I have a bit of an issue. I uninstalled and recompiled php 7.3.33 from source as I needed it to use openSSL and not NSS. It runs fine from terminal, but when i enter the IP on the browser, all I see is printed out PHP as html. Anyone knows the fix?

[Main page of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5VBo.png)

Comment: Did you reconfigure Apache to use the new version of PHP

Comment: I am trying to find any config that points to the php version used, but to no avail. Could you guide me with that, please?

Comment: There must be 1000 tutorials out there https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-setup-apache-with-php-and-fastcgi-on-centos-and-rhel/

Comment: All of them make me download prebuilt php, that is probably compiled with nss. Is that the case?

Comment: You only need look for the part that tells you how to configure fastcgi, you dont need to do the whole process

Comment: Great, now my apache doesnt run at all
Invalid command 'ScriptAlias/cgi-canister/"/var/www/cgi-receptacle/"', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
doesnt seem to be correct

Comment: Do those 2 quotes in the middle really exist

Comment: yes they do, will try to delete them

Comment: They are automatically generated :/

Comment: Im starting to suspect that the php source isnt compiled well. i installed normal php for a second and i had all the files in the guide, but after uninstalling it i dont even have a php.conf